# Track how many people visited your site from a banner app

Tags: android, google-analytics, banner

So I have a banner on a android application and I want to track how many people came to my site clicked that banner ?
What is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Tracking the source of your traffic from an app is no different from a webpage.

Onclick of your banner you might trigger a web URL like **site.com/page.html**.
You can add parameter to the URL by adding the source `site.com/page.html?source=app`

And then on your server side you can check for the query parameter to find from where this request was coming from.

Answer (score 0):

you have Several choices
you can send a parametr with your website's url , for example : 
http://www.yourdomain.com?sendFrom=app

you can use analytics libraries (such as fabric,facebook analytics, firebase ,...) and register events with these services when user clicks on your banner.

Answer (score 0):

The app isn't mine, only the add-banner, so I can't do anything app side. 
What about this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder